# Can I run Expo App over Local Network to IOS Simulator on my mac?

Tags: ios, linux, react-native, expo, simulator

I am using a Linux (Pop OS) system for developing the React Native app with Expo. I don't have an iPhone to test the app on IOS, but I do have a MacBook. Can I use the simulator that comes with MacBook to test the app without transferring the project from Linux (Pop OS) to Mac over a Local Network?

If yes, then please guide me on how.

I attempted to use Tunnel in Expo, but it failed as the simulator does not have the Expo Go app installed.